# Problem in simulating discrete time stochastic

Tags: random, simulation, stochastic-calculus

I have been playing with some stochastic questions and specially the problem [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23317/simulating-discrete-time-stochastic-dynamic-systems).It seems no matter for the first time in bet, gambler is going to lose the first bet.Am I right?How can we correct the algorithm here?

```
timstep = 5;
win = BinomialProcess[.99];
samplepaths = 1;
process = RandomFunction[Evaluate[win], {0, timstep - 1}, samplepaths];
ListLinePlot[process, Frame -> False, 
AxesLabel -> {Style["Time Step", Bold], Style["Number", Bold]}, 
PlotStyle -> {{Dashed, Black, Opacity[.9]}}, ImageSize -> 600]

x1 = 100;
alpha = 0.5;(*assume some value for alpha*)WinEvents = 
process["States"];
ST[WinEvents_?ListQ, x1_, alpha_, SimTime_] := 
Module[{}, 
FoldList[Max[If[#2 == 1, (1 + alpha) #1, (1 - alpha) #1], 0.] &, 
x1, Prepend[Differences@WinEvents, First@WinEvents]]];
simdat = ST[#, x1, alpha, timstep] & /@ WinEvents; Show[
ListLinePlot[Legended[Mean[simdat], ""], PlotRange -> All, 
PlotStyle -> {{AbsoluteThickness[3.5], Opacity[.9], Red}}, 
ImageSize -> 600], 
ListLinePlot[simdat, PlotRange -> All, 
PlotStyle -> {{Dashed, Black, Opacity[.7]}}], 
ListPlot[simdat, PlotRange -> All], Frame -> True]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: When you say "gambler is going to lose the first bet" I believe you're considering a value of $0$ a loss, while a value of $1$ would be a win, right? I think it's a visualization problem... remove `InterpolationOrder->0` and you will see that the first result can also be $1$.

Comment: @RodLm thanks,but please test it with second part of question.Still gambler loses the first ratio he is betting.No mater what he is losing.Regardless of visualization

Comment: What do you mean with "first ratio"?

Comment: Imagine that he has 100 and betting 20 in the beginning.He has to have either 80 or 120 after first bet.But here no matter how much chance we consider to the `BinomialProcess` he will start from 80 in the next round.How can you describe that?

Comment: The simulation starts at time t = 0. There are no wins until the second time point at t = 1.

Comment: @Alex In the BinomialProcess when you "lose" you actually receive $0$, so you cannot subtract any value from your previous "wealth".

Comment: @AndyRoss Hi Andy how can you describe my last question??No matter the time start from when he is losing first bet.Please look at the case.put 100 and see if you have 120 by any mean in the t=1

Comment: @RodLm do we have a moment we have 120 after first bet?

Comment: @RodLm put the chance on 99 percent you will se what I am talking about.

Comment: @AndyRoss please give one path and just 5 step,and put the chance in 0.99 you will se he is still losing the first bet!!!

Comment: @Alex When I simulate a single path with .99 win probability I'm getting (almost all the time) a straight line, which means a sequence of wins under Binomial processes...

Comment: @RodLm yes definitely.I am creating that sequence of win intentionally.Then simulate the next part of the question and see what will happen to the initial fortune of the gambler!!He will lose first step.

Comment: @Alex What I've done is not useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDITED**

Alex, I believe this is what you want:

```
StartingWealth = 100;
PercentChange = 0.5;
WinProbability = .5;
NumberOfProcesses = 2;
Time = 5;
processes = 
  RandomFunction[BinomialProcess[WinProbability], {0, Time}, 
  NumberOfProcesses];
  paths = Table[
  FoldList[Times, StartingWealth, 
  If[Differences[Last[Transpose[processes["Path", x]]]][[#]] == 
  1, (1 + PercentChange), (1 - PercentChange)] & /@ 
  Range[Time]], {x, 1, NumberOfProcesses}];
  ListLinePlot[Transpose[{Range[0, Time], Mean[paths]}], 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

However, I would advise your to simulate your paths using log-returns (instead of simple returns). This should help:

```
StartingWealth = 100;
PercentChange = 0.5;
WinProbability = .5;
NumberOfProcesses = 2;
Time = 5;
processes = 
  RandomFunction[BinomialProcess[WinProbability], {0, Time}, 
  NumberOfProcesses];
  paths = Table[
  FoldList[Times, StartingWealth, 
  If[Differences[Last[Transpose[processes["Path", x]]]][[#]] == 
  1, Exp[PercentChange], Exp[-PercentChange]] & /@ 
  Range[Time]], {x, 1, NumberOfProcesses}];
  ListLinePlot[Transpose[{Range[0, Time], Mean[paths]}], 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**EDITED**

Alex, to "prove" that arithmetic returns (i.e., gamblers wealth using arithmetic percent increase/decrease) are **downwards** biased, consider the comparison between log(geometric) returns and arithmetic returns:

```
StartingWealth = 100;
PercentChange = .5;
WinProbability = .5;
NumberOfProcesses = 5;
Time = 20;
processes = RandomFunction[BinomialProcess[WinProbability], {0, Time}, NumberOfProcesses];
ArithmeticPaths = Table[FoldList[Times, StartingWealth, 
  If[Differences[Last[Transpose[processes["Path", x]]]][[#]] == 1, 
    (1 + PercentChange), (1 - PercentChange)] & /@ Range[Time]], 
    {x, 1, NumberOfProcesses}];
GeometricPaths = Table[FoldList[Times, StartingWealth, 
  If[Differences[Last[Transpose[processes["Path", x]]]][[#]] == 1, 
  Exp[PercentChange], Exp[-PercentChange]] & /@ Range[Time]], 
  {x, 1, NumberOfProcesses}];
ListLinePlot[
  {Transpose[{Range[0, Time], Mean[GeometricPaths]}],
  Transpose[{Range[0, Time], Mean[ArithmeticPaths]}]}, 
    PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}, {Thick, Red}}, 
    PlotLegends -> {"Geometric Returns", "Arithmetic Returns"}]
```

[image]

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Alex, I believe there are two main problems in your simulation.

**FIRST PROBLEM**

You're interested in computing the **mean** of the processes. So, you have to be aware of the fact that *Mathematica* will actually plot the mean of the processes in a **different time scale** than that of your processes. For instance, to simulate two processes for a 5-period timestep you can write

```
processes = RandomFunction[BinomialProcess[.5], {0, 5}, 2]
```

This will return a `TemporalData[]` object. Now consider to "open" this `TemporalData[]` object:

```
processes["Path", 1]
processes["Path", 2]
```

and you will get something like

> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 2}, {5, 2}}
>
> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}}

Now you can see that the **first** simulated values occur **always** at **time zero** and its value will also (always) be **zero** (i.e., `{0, 0}`).

Now consider taking the **mean** of the processes:

```
Mean[processes["States"]]
```

and you will get something like

> {0, 1, 3/2, 2, 5/2, 3}

Now if you **plot** the mean vector the first value will start at **time one** and will end at time **six**, while the processes themselves will start at time zero and will end - correctly - at time five. See:

```
ListLinePlot[processes, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}];
ListLinePlot[Mean[processes["States"]], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}];
```

[image]

[image]

So, instead of using `Mean[processes["States"]]`, you should use

```
Mean[processes["Paths"]]
```

and your plot will be correct:

```
ListLinePlot[Mean[processes["Paths"]]]
```

[image]

**SECOND PROBLEM**

In order to compute the "wealth over time" of the gambler you have to be aware of the difference between **normal returns** and **logarithmic returns**.

You can find a very interesting introduction [here](http://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ424/returnCalculations.pdf).

In your simulation you use $(1+\alpha)$ and $(1-\alpha)$ while computing the wealth of the gambler. This leads you to a serious problem, because a gambler with starting wealth of $100$ after losing 50% will **never** come back to the original value after a gain of 50%. He will have to gain 100% (after losing 50%) to come back to the original value.

In this case, if you use $(1+\alpha)$ and $(1-\alpha)$ (where $\alpha$ represents a fixed percent gain/loss) you will be biasing the gambler's wealth **downwards**.

However, if you use Log-Returns the gambler's wealth can be correctly computed. Consider, for instance, an initial log-return of -50%:

```
100*Exp[-.5]
```

> 60.6531

After a log-return of +50% the gambler will have the original wealth:

```
%*Exp[.5]
```

> 100.

Now, consider that the gambler will gain +50% at the first moment

```
100*Exp[.5]
```

> 164.872

If he log-loses 50% he will have the original wealth back:

```
%*Exp[-.5]
```

> 100.

Comment: Hi .it wont work in my com by changing simply to `"Paths"`.No plot at all!

Comment: @Alex You must rewrite your entire code... did you understand the log-returns problem?

Comment: Many thanks for explanation Rod.OK.I will I will figure it out.

Comment: Hi Rod nice job great work.I hope really one day could be able to code like this !!

Answer (score 2):

Change your process definition to:

```
process = RandomFunction[Evaluate[win], {1, timstep}, samplepaths];
```

and you will avoid the first (zero) step. This is (I suspect) what Andy Ross was saying. The output of the above code (with the process defined as above) is the plot:

[image]

which has all increasing values because the coefficient of the binomial is 0.99

Comment: and it works for you?no change in my outlet

Comment: If you are getting something different, quit the kernel and try again.